# MD5 hashes and Regular Expressions

Tags: md5

I received a `MD5` hash and a `Regular Expression` which have the same plaintext..
How do I use the `Regular Expression` to crack the `MD5` hash and find the text behind the `MD5`?

```
b89e49cab317f2681be60fb3d1c0f8f8
[(a|c|d)n-t\|]{8}
```

Comment: This site is not for your purposes (explicitly for above question)

Comment: Did whoever crafted this puzzle for you not intend for you to solve it yourself?

Comment: It is possible to give people an outline of how to approach the problem without solving it for them. Please work to make stackoverflow a more welcoming environment.

Answer (score 2):

The idea would be to use the regex as a template and generate inputs that satisfy it.

You can search for a [regex visualizer](https://regexper.com/#%5B%28a%7Cc%7Cd%29n-t%5C%7C%5D%7B8%7D) to see this, but what that one says is any of the characters `()acd|` or any character between `n` and `t` (inclusive) in any order, repeated eight times. I tested this in hashcat, and the regex is correct despite it looking like it means something else. A shorter way to write that would be `[acd|()n-t]{8}`.

So you start generating 8 character strings with those values and taking the md5 of them. You can do this in almost any programming language but Python is a good choice. Look up the hashlib library, it has a function md5. You'll call the function hexdigest on that and compare it to the provided hash.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5(b'cybering').hexdigest()
'61e4feebe66ad22349e292d1462afd3a'
```

Additionally, if you want to use cracking software, look up JohnTheRipper or hashcat. You should be able to provide them a dictionary and have it attempt to break the hash. I was able to solve this with hashcat on my 980ti in ~5 seconds. [This tutorial](https://www.4armed.com/blog/perform-mask-attack-hashcat/) helped me set up the custom charset and mask to perform the attack.

Have fun!

Comment: Yeah. It’s valid regex but it doesn’t look like it is what the author intended it to be. But who knows.

Comment: 13 options, 8 characters; 13^8 = 815,730,721 possible combinations. Shouldn’t take too much time. Would be curious how long it would take. Heh

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan 5 seconds on a 980ti with hashcat.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to generate all possible eight-character combinations (with repetition) of the 19 characters allowed by the regex. Test each combination by computing the md5 hash and comparing it to the one you were given.

That would be 13^8 = 815,730,721 possible combinations to check. The answer will likely be found before checking all of them.

I was able to whip out a little Node.js program on my laptop that found the solution in about 4 minutes (I split the problem up using workers to take advantage of multiple CPU cores).

Edit: I thought the regex had `n-z` instead of `n-t` so the search space was actually much smaller.

Comment: Yes, probably he should have used the regex to figure out the domain of the original string, and then bruteforce it. However, in 2012, I suspect a brute force might have taken a bit longer, than it does today.

Comment: Where did you get 19 characters? I got 13 allowed characters: `()acd|nopqrst`.

Answer (score 0):

You cant crack the md5 hash value it has used one way hashing algorithm.

Comment: He told me to use the Regular Expression to 'reverse' or 'crack' the md5 hash and find the text..